# variables in slim rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I have template written with Slim, and I want to use it with Ruby but I have these errors in `index.slim`.

```
   -content_panel_file = '_partials/content_panel_5'
   -content_box_file = '_partials/content_box_2'
   - menu_file = '_partials/menu_side'
   = render  '_partials/template'
```

In template.slim:

```
.content-i
        .content-box
          == Slim::Template.new(content_box_file).render(Object.new, 'template_vars' => template_vars)
```

but it gave this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `content_box_file' for #<#<Class:0x00000003b28308>:0x00000003b685c0>
Did you mean?  content_for
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is your `content_box_file` doesn't exist in your partial file, you're trying to access a local variable that's not in the current "scope".

Try passing your `content_box_file` variable as a local one within your render method:

```
= render partial: '_partials/template', locals: { content_box_file: content_box_file }
```

Note you need to use `render partial: ...`.

Complete workflow:

```
# model/index.html.slim
- content_box_file = 'app/views/_partials/content_box_2.slim'
= render partial: '_partials/template', locals: { content_box_file: content_box_file }

# _partials/_template.html.slim:
- template_vars = 'Hallo'
== Slim::Template.new(content_box_file).render(Object.new, template_vars: template_vars)

# _partials/content_box_2.html.slim:
== template_vars
```

Comment: thnx for your response i tried that but i got the same error

Comment: You're not specifying it as a partial @mar use `= render partial: '...'`.